# How to iterate a scrapy spider over several nested lists?

Tags: python, scrapy, nested-lists

I am new to coding and am trying to use scrapy to obtain the titles of google scholar searches given very specified search terms.

Basically, I have a list of 600 names, for which I need to acquire the first 30 search terms within a specific year (2005-2020) for a series of query names.

Modifying code written by Ian Kerins (https://dev.to/iankerins/build-your-own-google-scholar-api-with-python-scrapy-4p73), I've figured out how to acquire the results for 1 species for 1 query in 1 year, but I am having trouble nesting my code in a way that I'll be able to scale this code and integrate over a series of multiple lists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import json
#import pandas
from datetime import datetime

API_KEY = '9c599caad9864e44e76ece2feb43dae7'
YEAR = '2005'

def get_url(url):
        payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}
        proxy_url = 'http://api.scraperapi.com/?' + urlencode(payload)
        return proxy_url

  
class ScholarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scholar'
    allowed_domains = ['api.scraperapi.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        queries = ['(Extinct OR Extinction) AND ("Loxodonta africana" OR "african elephant")']
        for query in queries:
            url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?' + urlencode({'hl': 'en', 'q': query,'as_ylo':YEAR,'as_yhi':YEAR})
            yield scrapy.Request(get_url(url), callback=self.parse, meta={'position': 0})

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        position = response.meta['position']
        for res in response.xpath('//*[@data-rp]'):
            link = res.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').extract_first()
            temp = res.xpath('.//h3/a//text()').extract()
            if not temp:
                title = "[C] " + "".join(res.xpath('.//h3/span[@id]//text()').extract())
            else:
                title = "".join(temp)
            snippet = "".join(res.xpath('.//*[@class="gs_rs"]//text()').extract())
            cited = res.xpath('.//a[starts-with(text(),"Cited")]/text()').extract_first()
            temp = res.xpath('.//a[starts-with(text(),"Related")]/@href').extract_first()
            related = "https://scholar.google.com" + temp if temp else ""
            num_versions = res.xpath('.//a[contains(text(),"version")]/text()').extract_first()
            published_data = "".join(res.xpath('.//div[@class="gs_a"]//text()').extract())
            position += 1
            item = {'Title': title, 'Author': published_data, 'Year': YEAR}
            yield item
        next_page = response.xpath('//td[@align="left"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            url = "https://scholar.google.com" + next_page
            yield scrapy.Request(get_url(url), callback=self.parse,meta={'position': position})
```

and here is what it produces:

[image: CSV created after running scrapy through my terminal]

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could get you more feedback, or even help you figure out the issue for yourself.

Comment: So you want 2005, 2006 and so on? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a spider...You may be better off using Scrapy's Crawler method, and then flatten your nested output at the end.